# Airline ticket reservation, spaces removed from lastname

Tags: air-travel, airlines, airport-security

I booked a flight ticket through an external website. The ticket I received shows my last name as one word even though it's two words. (Instead of "Full Name" it says "Fullname"). Can this be a problem at check-in?

Comment: Extremely unlikely. In my experience names on tickets often have various liberties taken with them.  For example, John Doe could become *DOE, JOHNMR* or even, formerly, *DOE, JMR.*

Comment: No problem at the counter with a real person (with a brain). Online checkin _might_be problematic - I have that continuously as my company insists of gluing my middle initial to my first name when booking, but my passport not, so it doesn't _exactly match_.

Comment: My wife & I frequently end up with tickets for which my first name and middle name are concatenated like this.  It's never been a problem so far.

Comment: Does it also say your names glued together when you try the "manage my booking" function on the airline web page? Quite often, this is just a display error on the "eticket".

Comment: My wife has has her middle name concatenated to either her first or last name on flight tickets and not had any issues boarding the flights.

Comment: My family name comes in three parts and the last part is the main one, when flying I have seen at least 4 days the name has been contracted and combined with Mrs or first name. Only one airline seems to be able to handle the name properly on the tickets and boarding passes, the one that used to be the national one here.

Comment: I've noticed with suffixes, United prints LAZARUSJR while Virgin has LAZARUS JR, and likewise for online retrieval of reservation. Whatever.

Comment: I don't think my wife has ever flown on a ticket that didn't have missing spaces.  It's harmless.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**You're fine.** I have a space in my last name, and it's probably 50/50 that the space makes it through on a ticket, list of participants in an event, insurance policy, or anything else in life. It's only on rare occasion (taking a standardized admissions test; receiving nuclear launch authorization) that the other party really cares about the name on their side precisely matching my legal name. For something like air travel, it's not an issue.

Comment: So tell me, how often have you received the nuclear launch authorization? \*looking up the addresses of nearby nuclear bunkers\*

Answer (score 5):

As far as I know, international air travel standards allow up to three errors in ticket's fields. Even if space removal counted as error, that's just one.

In practice, it seems pretty allowing, for example, I've flew with my first and last names swapped without problems.

UPD: I'm struggling to find any formal confirmations to my "three errors" factoid, unfortunately, so your mileage may vary. But there are confirmations that you may ask the airline to correct it, and if they refuse ask them to make a note on your ticket that such issue exists.

Comment: Any source to this claim. Looks very interesting.

Comment: This is my personal experience as well, I flew internationally with three typos in my name. Funny how they sometime still get it wrong over the phone even with spelling and re-spelling again and again.