# spaces removed from last name after buying a ticket from third party

Tags: air-travel

I saw this thread before ([Airline ticket reservation, spaces removed from lastname](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/76821/airline-ticket-reservation-spaces-removed-from-lastname)). But I would like to refresh it and be sure maybe others have same problem. While booking I was totally sure that I write my surname exactly as passport (ABCDOLLAHH MIRI). However, I saw in my ticket it was written as ABCDOLLAHHMIRI. I checked again in my profile while booking I wrote separately. I asked the airline they said that talk with your agency. I talked with them they told me that regarding the internal rules and IATA this kind of problems should not cause an issue since all the other data are correct and they can easily check. Also, I am not sure some people say that in some systems spaces or punctuations cannot be understood by the system. As far as I understand people in the past has not had any problem. Other passport data is correct.
So, anybody has any idea also or any experience?

Answer (score 2):

That's a programming problem you encountered.

It is most likely that   (Space) is not a valid character in the surname column of the software used. So it gets nixed in transfer into that system. Just like some airlines don't manage the `-` character in their first name columns - and then either nix it, reject the data or replace it with a  .

Comment: @ Trish. Thank you. So, no worries right? I dont know why airlines customer service never answers or guide correctly...

Comment: Generally, customs and airline workers are familiar with that kind of problem and make little hazzle, some might complain but it is an airline side problem. Data field compatibility is a major problem in projects, so often things get fudged that create these edge cases.

Comment: Since most people reserve from third party agency and I also did due to being cheaper. The ailine itself (customer serivce) referred me to the travel agency. Agency assured me about that. So you mean in the counter while giving our luggage and getting the tag there is no problem right?

Comment: @AhmadTurani usually it will be no problem, unless you have a stiffer that doesn't like your nose